# Avoid to kill project without reducing scope

Tags: scrum, scope, team, distributed-team, schedule

Within a project, we develop an application.
The project is set up as follows:

- The overall application is divided into four different "level". We completed one of those levels in four month.
- We use scrum with a one week sprints-duration incl. estimation of complexity. But we miss often our sprint goal and shift tasks to the next week.

The project team consists of:

- One consultant and PM
- Three developers: Two are developing the back-end and one is developing the front-end part of the application
- One remote developer for front-end tasks
- There is also a subcontractor company for some tasks.

Our plan for the close future is:

- Finish two other "levels" within one month (we working on one of these "level" for two months aleready). The focus shifted from back-end to front-end work (where we have just one developer, incuding one remote developer)
- We are aware that the schedule is quite tight

What would be the best way to deal with this situation, taking the team constellation and the scheduling into account?

I am thinking of switching to Kanban for the entire project, like [here](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12565/reduce-scope-or-kill-the-project)

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are asking. Can you remove the non-essential information and clarify your question please?

Comment: I heavily edited your question so please check, if I got everything right.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask if Kanban is going to help you deliver, it won't. Actually, none of the methods will.

There is the [project management triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management_triangle). If the time which says that you cannot have all the angles - scope, schedule, and cost - fixed. If your scope and schedule are fixed, the only thing is left for you is to hire more people that increases cost, increases communication, which risks the schedule.

If I understood correctly, you did one layer in 4 months and plan to do another two in one month. It is very unlikely that you'll be successful, so if I were you I'd started to communicate a scope reduction and find a way to iteratively roll out the not delivered layers. Since you are a small team, has no external dependencies Scrum can help you to focus and deliver. I don't see a reason why you should change the development method, you have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Zsolt, and would add that you are better off determining the amount and sources of schedule increase from the first chunk of 4-month work, and then applying that to future projections. This could be as simple as "we underestimated by 50%, therefore we will probably underestimate future work by 50%" all the way to "of the 50%: 10% was due to unknowns/emerging work, 25% was due to stakeholder feedback, and 15% was due to a risky feature not going as planned". The second approach is obviously much more actionable, since you can apply it a bit more effectively - discussing how to mitigate feedback through early alignment or simply prioritizing it better, evaluating remaining risky features a bit more thoroughly, etc.